# Configuring clang-format for isocpp's core guidelines

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want to follow the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) as close as possible but I have some problems configuring clang-format.

How do I configure clang-format to conform with the isocpp core guidelines?

For example the following guideline gives me some trouble.

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rl-ptr

clang-format always seems to choose `T &operator[](size_t);` and I am unable to find the correct setting for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `.clang-format`

```
PointerAlignment: Left
```

You can test it online in the [clang-format-configurator](http://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/)